# 18.04 LTS - Is there a installation candidate for the emovix package?

Tags: 18.04, k3b

Installed K3B on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS.  The emovix dependency, and/or optional programme is not installed.  The **emovix** and/or **movixmaker-2** packages are not in the 18.04 repos - is there a way to install this, or were they simply not packaged for 18.04?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see the following:

1. Global package search on https://pkgs.org [show results with 0.8.4 version](https://pkgs.org/download/movixmaker) only from Debian 7 (*wheezy*) and related Ubuntu 14.04 LTS (*trusty*).
2. Search on the https://repology.org [show the same 0.8.4](https://repology.org/metapackage/movixmaker-2/versions) in Debian and children.

But you can install this package manually on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS with the following commands:

```
wget http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/universe/m/movixmaker-2/movixmaker-2_0.8.4-2_all.deb
sudo apt install ./movixmaker-2_0.8.4-2_all.deb
```

but it will not work with error:

> ```
> $ movixmaker-2  
> Can't use 'defined(@array)' (Maybe you should just omit the defined()?) at /usr/bin/movixmaker-2 line 214.
> ```

so this package seems to be abandoned.

The last possibility is to get files from SourceForge [file pages](https://sourceforge.net/projects/movix/files/):

```
wget https://datapacket.dl.sourceforge.net/project/movix/eMoviX/0.9/emovix_0.9.0-1_all.deb
sudo apt install ./emovix_0.9.0-1_all.deb
```

and maybe others. This will result in:

> ```
> $ movix-version 
> 0.9.0
> ```